# Where do I place an error object in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, coding-style

In my current PHP website, I am passing around strings describing errors. I want to move away from this hacky system and use error codes instead, so I've created this error object:

```
class Error 
{
   const DATABASE = 0; // database failure
   const CACHE    = 1; // cache miss
   const NETWORK  = 2; // network is down
   // ... etc ...
}
```

What is the standard folder to place this file in CodeIgniter and what is the standard way to load such a file in a controller?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just put it in `/application/libraries/` (See [Creating Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) for CodeIgniter conventions).

You would then load the library like this:

```
$this->load->library('yourErrorClass');
```

..and use one of its functions like this:

```
$this->yourErrorClass->someLoggingFunction();
```